# xmldoc.Childnodes.item() question

Tags: c#, element, xmldocument, appendchild

I decided to try out the tutorial on this website

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/05/creating-a-xml-document-with-c/

Here's my code, which is more or less the same but a bit easier to read

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class Mainclass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlDocument xmldoc;
        XmlNode node1;
        node1 = XmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, "", "");
        XmlDoc.AppendChild(node1);

        XmlElement element1;
        element1 = XmlDoc.CreateElement("", "ROOT", "");

        XmlText text1;
        text1 = XmlDoc.CreateTextNode("this is the text of the root element");

        element1.AppendChild(text1);
        // appends the text specified above to the element1

        XmlDoc.AppendChild(element1);


        // another element

        XmlElement element2;
        element2 = XmlDoc.CreateElement("", "AnotherElement", "");

        XmlText text2;
        text2 = XmlDoc.CreateTextNode("This is the text of this element");
        element2.AppendChild(text2);

        XmlDoc.ChildNodes.Item(1).AppendChild(element2);
    }
}
```

So far, I'm liking XmlDocument, but I can't figure out how this line works

```
XmlDoc.ChildNodes.Item(1).AppendChild(element2);
```

Specifically, the Item() part of it

according to MSDN...

```
//
// Summary:
//     Retrieves a node at the given index.
//
// Parameters:
//   index:
//     Zero-based index into the list of nodes.
//
// Returns:
//     The System.Xml.XmlNode in the collection. If index is greater than or equal
//     to the number of nodes in the list, this returns null.
```

However, I'm still not really sure what "index" refers to, or what Item() does. Does it move down the tree or down a branch?

Also, when I was looking at it, I thought it would end up like this

**what I thought would happen:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>this is the text of the root element</ROOT>
<AnotherElement>This is the text of this element</AnotherElement>
```

but it ended up like this

**Actual output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>this is the text of the root element
      <AnotherElement>This is the text of this element</AnotherElement>
</ROOT>
```

(formatting added)

Comment: Before you put too much time in this, make sure you know about linq2xml (XDocument vs XmlDocument). XDocunent is the new API that is usually preferred.

Comment: the only reason I picked XmlDocument is because I'm having trouble figuring out the new keywords in .NET 3.0, such as "from".

Answer (score 2):

The `ChildNodes` property returns the `XmlNodeList` of *immediate* children of what you call it on. `Item` then finds the nth member of that list. It won't recurse into grand-children etc. In particular, I believe in this case `Item(0)` would return the XML declaration, and `Item(1)` returns the root element. A nicer way of expressing "get to the root element" would be to use `XmlDocument.DocumentElement`.

Note that your "expected" output wouldn't even be valid XML - an XML document can only have one root element.

To be honest, this isn't a terribly nice use of it - and in particular I would recommend using LINQ to XML rather than `XmlDocument` if you possibly can. It's not particularly clear what you're trying to achieve with the code you've given, but it would almost certainly be *much* simpler in LINQ to XML.

Comment: @jwaffe: I suggest you practice LINQ to XML instead of `XmlDocument` :)

Comment: Do you know where I could get a good explanation of the new keywords in .net 3.0? The MSDN site has a mistake in it, and I'm having a hard time finding definitions

Comment: @jwaffe: Keywords are typically in *languages*, and .NET 3.0 didn't introduce any new language features. What kind of thing are you talking about?

Comment: "from', for instance the last part of the example on this site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

I don't know what "from", "in", "where", and "select" mean.

Comment: @jwaffe: That's C# 3 (part of .NET 3.5) not .NET 3.0. Where is the mistake you think you've found? As for good explanations - might I recommend my book, C# in Depth? :) (http://manning.com/skeet2)